# What is the easiest fastest way to implement spring MVC 3.0 login and filter accessible pages with it`?

Tags: security, spring-mvc, authentication, admin

Suddenly, a wild login-screen appears. I didn't think about this at all when i started my project, but so far i've seen that Spring does these things pretty well without changing all of my work done so far. Can anyone tell me the easiest way to do implement an admin-login.

Links and examples appreciated :)!

Comment: Use Spring Security. It is well documented and default minimum configuration provide solutions for simply login mechanism: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found quite  a few  useful tutorials for this

```
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html

http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/07/07/5-minute-guide-to-spring-security/
```

each of these sum up the process nicely.